# How to call jquery function from another page in laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I have one page called  `modals.blade.php`  in this I am performing an insert operation. This modal I am using on another page called `view.blade.php`. And the same modal I am using in other pages with different logic (the fields will be changing)

I need to call a function of view.blade.php from modals.blade.php after successful insertion. whether it is possible?

pages

modals.blade.php

```
<div class="modal fade" id="paymentModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <form id="paymentform" method="post">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
           modal body 
        </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
            </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#paymentform').on('submit',function(event){

    event.preventDefault();

    var formdata = $('#paymentform').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url:'{!! url('storepayment') !!}',
        dataType:'json',
        method:'post',
        data: formdata,
        success:function(data)
        {
            getAllPayments();  //  Calling this function from another page
        }

    });

    });

});

</script>
```

view.blade.php

```
@include('invoice.modals')
<div class="row ">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <table class="table table-bordered" id="contactdata" >
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                  <th scope="col">SLNO</th>
                                  <th scope="col">Invoice ID</th>
                                  <th scope="col">Payment Method</th>
                                  <th scope="col">Payment Date</th>
                                  <th scope="col">Amount</th>
                                  <th scope="col">Notes</th>
                                  <th scope="col">edit</th>
                                </tr>
                              </thead>
                        </table>
                </div>
 </div>

<script>

    $(function() {

     getAllPayments();

        function getAllPayments()
        {
            var invoiceid = $('#invoiceid').val();    
            $('#contactdata').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            "bDestroy": true,
            "bAutoWidth": false,
            ajax:{
                "url" : '{!! url('payments') !!}',
                data :{
                    'invoiceid' : invoiceid
                },
            },
            columns: [
                    { data:'DT_RowIndex'},
                    { data: 'DT_RowData.data-invoice_id', name: 'invoice_id' },
                    { data: 'payment_method', name: 'payment_method' },
                    { data: 'payment_date', name: 'payment_date' },
                    { data: 'amount', name: 'amount' },
                    { data: 'notes', name: 'notes' },
                ]
            });
        }
 });
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: create separate js file for your getallPayments() method and include it to your blade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create separate js file for your method.

public/assets/js/myFunctions.js

```
function getAllPayments()
{
  //getting all payments
}
```

In your main layout add a @stack('scripts')

in your view.blade.php

```
@push('scripts')
 <script src="{{ asset('js/myFunctions.js')}}"></script>
@endpush
```

and you can now your method since it is included in your blade.

Comment: it will still work just include also the modal in your blade